# Free VBscript obfuscator

Tags: vbscript, obfuscation

Hi all
I have a reasonably large (2k lines) vbScript file which i need to obfuscate. It is a customised QTP function library so must be distributed with the product. Is there any free VBscript obfuscators out there that do a decent job?
Thanks!

EDIT:
Encryption is not suitable for use with QTP so Windows Scripting Encryption tools will not work, QTP has to be able to understand the output. I'm not trying to make the output hacker proof, just so the casual programmer cant be bothered to put the effort in to de-obfuscate it

Comment: [VBShaker](http://da440dil.narod.ru/vbshaker.html) - VBScript code obfuscation

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's a Little script i whipped up for you that will obfuscate any `vbs` file....

The obfuscation is pretty simple, so anyone familiar with `vbs` can prolly de-obfuscate it in 1 min.

If you want higher level of obfuscation, well you need to pay me... :) but for this i'll take your votes! :D

The resulting script `obfuscated.vbs` will remain a valid `vbs` file.

I could've made a self decrypting vbs, but chances are that will cause a red-flag with an antivirus...and if your anti-virus is any good, it should flag this as suspicious.

Please note, *Standard disclaimer applies...I'm not responsible for any damage that maybe occur due to the script, use at own risk. I don't guarantee it'll work all the time*

```
'VBS Obfuscator by st0le

Randomize
set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
fileName = Inputbox("Enter Path of the File to scramble : ")
set src = fso.OpenTextfile(fileName,1)
body = src.readall
set rep  = fso.createtextfile("Obfuscated.vbs",true)
rep.writeline "Execute(" & Obfuscate(body) & " ) "

Function Obfuscate(txt)
enc = ""
for i = 1 to len(txt)
enc = enc & "chr( " & form( asc(mid(txt,i,1)) ) & " ) & "
next
Obfuscate = enc & " vbcrlf "
End Function


Function form(n)

r = int(rnd * 10000)
k = int(rnd * 3)
if( k = 0) then ret = (r+n) & "-" & r
if( k = 1) then ret = (n-r) & "+" & r
if( k = 2) then ret = (n*r) & "/" & r
form = ret
End Function
```

Comment: Hehe, perfect for keeping nosy business people out of the test scripts. Thanks a lot mate!

Comment: Found this implemented here:   https://isvbscriptdead.com/vbs-obfuscator/

Comment: @JustYY, Ha! I don't mind. I'm pretty sure I got this off a computer virus.

Comment: I tried converting my vbs file with the code above by St0le. The obfuscated file file was created. When I tried to run it, the computer says I don't have permission and my Kaspersky showed me that active malware is running. Anyway I granted Kaspersky permission. It ran the antivirus, deleted the obfuscated file and restarted the computer. @st0le

Answer (score 0):

In Windows XP, you can use [WSH Script Encoder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cbfz3598%28VS.85%29.aspx).
Note that this has been [reverse-engineered](http://www.virtualconspiracy.com/content/scrdec/intro).

Comment: Thanks mate, i'll have a look into it

Comment: I had a look into it, it doesnt work for this case and this is the reason. WSH Script Encoder 'encrypts' the vbs (making it into a vbe file) which QTP can no longer execute. Its a great solution but it isnt obfuscated, its encrypted. +1 for finding a solution to encrypting script languages tho, didnt know it was possible

Answer (score 0):

I found a free online vbscript obfuscator that utilizes a stack of obfuscation techniques (as well as formatting and minimization): [vbsobfuscator.com](http://www.vbsobfuscator.com)