# Convert .vbs file into format that hides code

Tags: vbscript, file-format

How could I convert a ".vbs" file into a format that hides the actual code?

I have a script which needs to be shared across multiple people, so to keep the script safe I want to convert it to executable format which hides the code.
How do I go about doing this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Free VBscript obfuscator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4252419/free-vbscript-obfuscator)

Answer (score 0):

I've flagged this dupe and pointed to the code obfuscation answer: [Free VBscript obfuscator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4252419/free-vbscript-obfuscator)

But if you want a true .exe you could translate your script to VB.NET. The syntax is similar and compiles to a true binary. If you don't have Visual Studio, there is a free version: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-express-vs.aspx

Answer (score 0):

> Using this handy VBS tool, you can convert your VBScript into an
>   obfuscated VBS source code, without compromising/altering the
>   scripting functionalities and the VBScript keywords. This Free
>   VBScript Obfuscator works by converting each character in your VBS
>   source code into a much obfuscated format. Then these obfuscated
>   letters are combined at runtime and be executed via the Execute
>   function.

https://isvbscriptdead.com/vbs-obfuscator/