# How do I encode my VBScript files into .vbe files?

Tags: encoding, vbscript

I have a simple .vbs file that I would like to encode into .vbe.  I've looked all over to see how to do it or what tools I would need and haven't found anything on it.  Here's the code:

```
message=InputBox("What do you want me to say?","Type message here.")
Set sapi=CreateObject("sapi.spvoice")
sapi.Speak message
```

If there is any other way to turn the .vbs into a non human readable file, that would work too.

Comment: There's a VBS-VBE tool here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32882622/convert-vbs-encrypted-script-to-string

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Free VBscript obfuscator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4252419)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert vbs encrypted script to string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32882622)